# SQL: get a substring using a delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column which has `-` as delimiter and I want to get substring between the first and second delimiter:

```
ABC-DEF-FG
ABCD-JAFF-UIOU-TYU
```

Output

```
DEF
JAFF
```

I have tried substring and charIndex but not getting exactly what I wanted

```
select * SUBSTRING(column, CHARINDEX('-', column)+1, len(column)) 
from table

select * SUBSTRING(column, CHARINDEX('-', column)+1, charindex('-', column, (charindex('-', column, 1)))) 
from table

select * SUBSTRING(column, CHARINDEX('-', column)+1, charindex('-', column, (charindex('-', column, 1))+1)) 
from table
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: Failed to execute query. Error: 'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @user09 What version on you using   SELECT @@version

Comment: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 May 12 2022 23:11:24 Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a bit of JSON

**Example**

```
Select A.[column] 
      ,Pos2  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]')
From  YourTable A
Cross Apply ( values ( '["'+replace(string_escape([column],'json'),'-','","')+'"]' ) ) B(S)
```

**Results**

```
column              Pos2
ABC-DEF-FG          DEF
ABCD-JAFF-UIOU-TYU  JAFF
```

Comment: Can confirm that this is how I'd do it on MSSQL.

Comment: @Stoff Yes, SQL Server 2016+  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0c5ae1432cd383d4ca5e188af3e5884e

Comment: @Stoff Easy to expand ... note the pattern /index   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4d5e4a48e730995d31c9228cb8c22fab

Comment: @JohnCappelletti this works. can you pls explain

Comment: @John Capalletti, you misunderstand - I AM confirming that this works. No need for me to take a peek. Like stated, I CONFIRM that this is how I would do it in MSSQL aswell.

Comment: @Stoff Ahh.   Got it.

Comment: @user09  The CROSS APPLY converts you [column] into a JSON string.   Then it is a small matter to grab the INDEX 1 via json_value()

Comment: @user09 take a moment and look at the 2nd dbFiddle link in the comments above.

Comment: how can I add where condition to this query like ```where Pos2 not in ('ABCD', 'IOP')```

Comment: @user09 Just add WHERE  JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]') not in ('ABCD', 'IOP')

Comment: @user09 If you don't want to get JSON_VALUE(...) twice, you can use a second CROSS APPLY and ref Pos2   Exmple:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=19c70df41098d2fd51a3ee69d20ca0e5

Comment: appreciate any help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028249/spring-jdbctemplate-use-query-with-json-as-input-for-jdbc-tempalte